# How to build historgram of methods by time spent inside with Mono?

Tags: mono, profiling

I have tried the following:

```
mono --profile=log myprog.exe
```

to collect profiler data. Then to interpret those I invoke:

```
> mprof-report output.mlpd 

Mono log profiler data
        Profiler version: 2.0
        Data version: 14
        Arguments: log
        Architecture: x86-64
        Operating system: linux
        Mean timer overhead: 51 nanoseconds
        Program startup: Fri Jul 20 00:11:12 2018
        Program ID: 19840
        Server listening on: 59374

JIT summary
        Compiled methods: 8349
        Generated code size: 2621631
        JIT helpers: 0
        JIT helpers code size: 0

GC summary
        GC resizes: 0
        Max heap size: 0
        Object moves: 0

Metadata summary
        Loaded images: 16
        Loaded assemblies: 16

Exception summary
        Throws: 0

Thread summary
        Thread: 0x7fb49c50a700, name: ""
        Thread: 0x7fb49d27b700, name: "Threadpool worker"
        Thread: 0x7fb49d07a700, name: "Threadpool worker"
        Thread: 0x7fb49ce79700, name: "Threadpool worker"
        Thread: 0x7fb49cc78700, name: "Threadpool worker"
        Thread: 0x7fb49d6b9700, name: ""
        Thread: 0x7fb4bbff1700, name: "Finalizer"
        Thread: 0x7fb4bfe3f740, name: "Main"

Domain summary
        Domain: (nil), friendly name: "myprog.exe"
        Domain: 0x1d037f0, friendly name: "(null)"

Context summary
        Context: (nil), domain: (nil)
```

However, there's no information concerning which methods were called often and took long to complete, which was the only one thing I expected from profiling.

How do I use Mono profiling to gather and output information about method calls' total run time? Like `hprof` with `cpu=times` will generate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mono docs are "slightly" wrong as the methods `calls` are not tracked by default. This option creates huge profile log output and massively slows down "total" execution time and when combined with other options like `alloc`, effect the execution time of the methods and thus any timings that are being collected.

Personally I would recommend using `calls` profiling by itself adjusting the `calldepth`to a level that matters to your profiling. i.e. do you need to profile into the framework calls or not? Also a smaller call depth also greatly decreases the size of the log produced.

Example:

```
mono --profile=log:calls,calldepth=10 Console_Ling.exe
```

Produces:

```
Method call summary
Total(ms) Self(ms)      Calls Method name
   53358        0          1 (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)
   53358        2          1 Console_Ling.MainClass:Main (string[])
   53340        2          1 Console_Ling.MainClass:Stuff ()
   53337        0          3 System.Linq.Enumerable:ToList<int> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int>)
   53194    13347          1 System.Linq.Enumerable/WhereListIterator`1<int>:ToList ()
   33110    13181   20000000 Console_Ling.MainClass/<>c__DisplayClass0_0:<Stuff>b__0 (int)
   19928    13243   20000000 System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int>:Contains (int)
    6685     6685   20000000 System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer`1<int>:Equals (int,int)
    ~~~~
```

Re: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/profile/profiler/#profiler-option-documentation

Comment: while i'm fairly certain the old profiler docs mentioned how to restrict logs with only tracing calls by their namespace.  this information seems to have been removed from current profiler page.  however it still seems to be supported and it's very useful for keeping profiler logs manageable.   the syntax used is same mentioned on the mono debug page, eg to use two spacespaces the trace argument sufficies, eg: mono --profile=log:calls,calldepth=10 Console_Ling.exe --trace=N:MyApplication,System.Math